# PHP update multiple tables in one statement error

Tags: php, mysql

I have tried many solutions that I have found on stackoverflow but keep getting the same error when trying to update my tables within the one statement.

ERROR:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE docID=7' at line 2

Code:

```
  <?php

    if(isset($_POST['btn-revActivate']))
    {
      try
  {
        $database = new Database();
        $db = $database->dbConnection();
        $conn = $db;


    $stmt=$conn->prepare("UPDATE tbl_revisions, tbl_documents SET revStatus='Active', docStatus='Draft'
              WHERE revID=$rid AND docID=$docID ");
    $stmt->bindparam("revStatus",$revStatus);
    $stmt->bindparam(":id",$rid);
    $stmt->bindparam("docStatus",$docStatus);
    $stmt->bindparam(":docID",$docID);
    $stmt->execute();
    return true;

  }
  catch(PDOException $e)
  {
   echo $e->getMessage();
   return false;
  }
  }

   ?>
```

Can someone please help as I don't know what is wrong with this statement.
Thanks.

Comment: You're not using prepared statements correctly (for one thing).

Comment: @Fred-ii- it works individually fine but not updating multiple tables.

Comment: I don't see how that query generates that error.  The `WHERE` clause is different between the two.  Also note that your code is open to SQL injection, so I guess the `WHERE` clause in the error *could* be coming from user input?

Comment: None of your `bindparam()` calls are actually doing anything here, your code is likely vulnerable to sql injection.  The thing that is causing your problem is that it appears that `docID` is not in both tables.

Answer (score 1):

You can't update multiple tables in one statement.if you want to update then you can use a transaction to make sure that two UPDATE statements are treated atomically.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

UPDATE tbl_revisions

SET revStatus='Active', docStatus='Draft'
              WHERE revID=$rid AND docID=$docID ';

UPDATE tbl_documents
SET revStatus='Active', docStatus='Draft'
              WHERE revID=$rid AND docID=$docID ';

COMMIT;
```

for more information

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html